# Place <div> above <nav> element

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website for a client using a Wordpress theme I purchased off ThemeForest. [This is the page](http://test.doig.com.au/meyer/) in question, and it contains the following HTML:

```
<div class="container header-block">
  <div class="logo">
      <a href="http://test.doig.com.au/meyer/" class="site-logo-link" rel="home"></a>
            <div class="site-description">
                        <h3 class="sitename sitetitle"></h3>
            <p class="tagline"></p>
            </div>
    </div>
  <nav class="nav nav-horizontal"></nav>            
</div>
```

& CSS:

```
.header-left .logo {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.logo {
    padding: 0;
}
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
    list-style: none;
}

.header-site .nav {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
.header-site nav {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.nav-horizontal {
    display: block !important;
}
.nav {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I'd like to know how to place the logo above the div, so that it is like [this website](http://www.bluechipmortgages.com.au/finance-calculators/property-buying-cost-calculator).

I've tried using CSS:

```
.nav-horizontal {
  display: block !important;
}
```

but this didn't work.

Can you help please?

Comment: Hey, I am sorry, but I do not understand your question. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question, you want to display your logo above the navigation. You can achieve that by changing your html.

As you do not want to have your navigation inside your header, you can simply erase it.

```
<div class="container header-block">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="http://test.doig.com.au/meyer/" class="site-logo-link" rel="home"></a>
    <div class="site-description">
      <h3 class="sitename sitetitle"></h3>
      <p class="tagline"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Afterwards you can add it again below your header, wrapping it inside a container:

```
<div class="container">
   <nav class="nav nav-horizontal"></nav>
</div>
```

The **complete code** could look like this:

```
 <div class="container header-block">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="http://test.doig.com.au/meyer/" class="site-logo-link" rel="home"></a>
    <div class="site-description">
      <h3 class="sitename sitetitle"></h3>
      <p class="tagline"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Insert Navigation -->
<div class="container">
   <nav class="nav nav-horizontal"></nav>
</div>
```

This would be a clean method without changing too much of css stylesheets.